# Skipping lines while debugging Python with PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, ide

In some point of debugging PyCharm, it would be useful to me to skip some lines, e.g. some lines that slows terribly my code... but I haven't found anything about this.

Does it exists an option in PyCharm debugger (or python debugger) to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the program is paused on a breakpoint somewhere before those "heavy lines" - right click after them and select "Jump To Cursor".

Please note there are some limitations to this feature, e.g. one can't jump out of a function scope.

Comment: the fact is that the line isn't really skipped using jump to cursor...

Comment: They are, unless you used "Run to Cursor", which is a different action.